# How to transmit struct as an array?

Tags: c, serialization, casting, struct

I've got a `struct` with 3 16-bit values in an embedded system:

```
struct {
    uint16_t x;
    uint16_t y;
    uint16_t z;
};
```

The `struct` will be transmitted to another system running the same software on the same hardware. Transmission is done by sending a series of 8 8-bit values (`send_data(uint8_t *data)`).

My idea is just give `send_data` the address of the struct. The two final bytes would be considered garbage. Would this work? Is it safe?

Comment: Taking a dependency on the structure layout and byte order of the fields isn't the greatest idea.  Those two phantom bytes can certainly byte as well, triggering a processor fault.  But you can probably make it work.  Writing the code so this is never an issue certainly isn't something you should consider dismissing, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be safe as long as you handle it correctly on the other end (don't write the two bytes to a random location for example).

I would also suggest you comment the issue clearly in the code so future maintainers don't run into trouble.

---

OR

You could change the structure for sending and receiving to include an name (eg padding) for the data at the end.   This will allow you to null out those bytes before sending. Then the code should be quite clear to anyone working on it and if implemented right should have no effect on performance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Would this work? - Yes (send_data the address of the struct.)
2. Is it safe?  Operationally yes, but testing no.

Recommend to *not* send garbage.  Pad the data given to `send_data()` as needed (2 bytes) and initialize the extra to something, say 0.  This will ease debugging and make for consistent regression testing.